# Minifying a CSS and Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to increase the page speed of my charities webpage. One thing I have been told to do on google insights is to minify the CSS and Javascript code on the website. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: The insights contains a minifier for the both languages.

Comment: Are you using any build tools? else you can use online tools like https://www.minifier.org/

Comment: please read the guide before posting a question, so to avoid downvotes and get useful answers https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You could minify and use gzipping as well, to reduce the size of the files. Note: There is no use of minifying small files if they are present. What is?

**Minify**

> Minification does things like removing whitespace, removing comments,
>   removing non-required semicolons, reducing hex code lengths

[image]

**Gzipping**

> Gzipping finds all repetitive strings and replaces them with pointers
>   to the first instance of that string

Read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-minification-and-gzipping/). You could use online tools or task runners to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use task runners like `grunt` or `gulp`. 
They are tools that can handle multiple tasks like minifying CSS and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try these links:

To minify HTML:

- [minifier](https://www.minifier.org/)

To minify CSS:

- [CSSNano](https://github.com/ben-eb/cssnano)
- [csso](https://github.com/css/csso)

To minify JavaScrips:

- [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2)
- [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler)
- [very effective](https://github.com/samccone/The-cost-of-transpiling-es2015-in-2016#summary-of-findings)